# Excel macros (32 bit excel) in 64 bit

Tags: excel, vba

Im not good in Visual Basic but I have task to make macros from 32 bit windows excel available on 64 bit window :)

The task is to make EMF from Excel page - I`ve already changed "function" to "PtrSafe function" and "olepro32.dll" to "oleaut32.dll" but code is running with error - RunTime error "380" Invalid property value

```
Sub UpdateRtLogsandEMF()
Set This = ThisWorkbook
Dim aaa1 As Single
Dim aaa2 As Single
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
This.Worksheets("TempSQL").Visible = xlSheetVisible
This.Worksheets("TempLog").Visible = xlSheetVisible
This.Worksheets("TempLog").Select

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
sCon = This.Worksheets("TempSQL").Cells(1, 1)
cn.Open sCon

DrillDepthIndex = This.Worksheets("TempLog").Cells(1, 157)
DrillDepthIndex = "'" & DrillDepthIndex & "'"

WellPathIndex = This.Worksheets("TempLog").Cells(1, 154)
WellPathIndex = "'" & WellPathIndex & "'"

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
sql_query = "SELECT Depth FROM GENDATAINDEX WHERE GenDataSetId = " & DrillDepthIndex & "ORDER BY Time DESC"
rs.Open sql_query, cn
On Error Resume Next
sss = rs.Fields(0)
If sss = "" Then
This.Worksheets("Logs RT").Cells(14, 19) = ""
Else
This.Worksheets("Logs RT").Cells(14, 19) = Round(rs.Fields(0), 2)
End If
'This.Worksheets("Logs RT").Cells(14, 19) = Round(rs.Fields(0), 2)

Date1 = Format(Now, "yyyy.mm.dd")
Day1 = Right(Date1, 2)
Year1 = Left(Date1, 4)
Month1 = Mid(Date1, 6, 2)

If This.Worksheets("TempLog").Cells(1, 210) = "RUS" Then
dfd = 43
Else
dfd = 42
End If

This.Worksheets("Logs RT").Cells(11, 15) = Day1 & " " & This.Worksheets("Logs RT").Cells(Month1, dfd) & " " & Year1

This.Worksheets("Logs RT").Cells(12, 15) = Format(Now, "HH:mm")
This.Worksheets("Logs RT").Select

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
sql_query = "SELECT SRSP_S_VDEPTH FROM SURVEY_STATION WHERE PATH_IDENTIFIER = " & WellPathIndex & " ORDER BY SRSP_TIME DESC"
rs.Open sql_query, cn
On Error Resume Next
sss = rs.Fields(0)
If sss = "" Then
This.Worksheets("Logs RT").Cells(14, 62) = ""
Else
This.Worksheets("Logs RT").Cells(14, 62) = Round(rs.Fields(0), 2)
End If
If This.Worksheets("TempLog").Cells(9, 151) = True Then
aaa1 = apiGetSystemMetrics(0&)
aaa2 = apiGetSystemMetrics(1&)
ChangeResolution 1280, 960
End If

'  With Application.ErrorCheckingOptions
'        .TextDate = False
'        .NumberAsText = False
'        .InconsistentFormula = False
'        .UnlockedFormulaCells = False
'        .EmptyCellReferences = False
'    End With
    
'    If ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines Then
'        bGridOn = True
'        ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
'    End If
    
    Dim vFile As Variant, sFilter As String, lPicType As Long, oPic As IPictureDisp
    sFilter = "Windows Metafile (*.emf),*.emf"
    vFile = This.Worksheets("TempLog").Cells(1, 152) & "RT_header_MD.emf"

        lPicType = xlPicture
 
         This.Worksheets("Logs RT").Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(67, 32)).Select
        With Selection
            .CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
        End With
        Set oPic = PastePicture(lPicType)
        SavePicture oPic, vFile


    sFilter = "Windows Metafile (*.emf),*.emf"
    vFile = This.Worksheets("TempLog").Cells(1, 152) & "RT_header_TVD.emf"

        lPicType = xlPicture
         This.Worksheets("Logs RT").Range(Cells(2, 45), Cells(67, 75)).Select
        With Selection
            .CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
        End With
        Set oPic = PastePicture(lPicType)
        SavePicture oPic, vFile

 '   If bGridOn Then ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = True
     
'    With Application.ErrorCheckingOptions
'        .TextDate = True
'        .NumberAsText = True
'        .InconsistentFormula = True
'        .UnlockedFormulaCells = True
'        .EmptyCellReferences = True
'    End With
    
If This.Worksheets("TempLog").Cells(9, 151) = True Then
ChangeResolution aaa1, aaa2
End If
    
    
This.Worksheets("Logs RT").Select
This.Worksheets("TempSQL").Visible = xlSheetHidden
This.Worksheets("TempLog").Visible = xlSheetHidden
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Sub MakeRtLogsEMF()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set This = ThisWorkbook
Dim aaa1 As Single
Dim aaa2 As Single
If This.Worksheets("TempLog").Cells(9, 151) = True Then
aaa1 = apiGetSystemMetrics(0&)
aaa2 = apiGetSystemMetrics(1&)
ChangeResolution 1280, 960
End If

Set This = ThisWorkbook
'    With Application.ErrorCheckingOptions
'        .TextDate = False
'        .NumberAsText = False
'        .InconsistentFormula = False
'        .UnlockedFormulaCells = False
'        .EmptyCellReferences = False
'    End With
    
'    If ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines Then
'        bGridOn = True
'        ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
'    End If
    
    Dim vFile As Variant, sFilter As String, lPicType As Long, oPic As IPictureDisp
    sFilter = "Windows Metafile (*.emf),*.emf"
    vFile = This.Worksheets("TempLog").Cells(1, 152) & "RT_header_MD.emf"
    
        'Get the type of bitmap
        lPicType = xlPicture
    
        'Copy a picture to the clipboard
         This.Worksheets("Logs RT").Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(67, 32)).Select
        With Selection
            .CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
        End With

    
        'Retrieve the picture from the clipboard...
        Set oPic = PastePicture(lPicType)
    
        '... and save it to the file
        SavePicture oPic, vFile
        
    sFilter = "Windows Metafile (*.emf),*.emf"
    vFile = This.Worksheets("TempLog").Cells(1, 152) & "RT_header_TVD.emf"
    
        'Get the type of bitmap
        lPicType = xlPicture
    
        'Copy a picture to the clipboard
         This.Worksheets("Logs RT").Range(Cells(2, 45), Cells(67, 75)).Select
        With Selection
            .CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
        End With

    
        'Retrieve the picture from the clipboard...
        Set oPic = PastePicture(lPicType)
    
        '... and save it to the file
        SavePicture oPic, vFile

 '   If bGridOn Then ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = True
'
'    With Application.ErrorCheckingOptions
'        .TextDate = True
'        .NumberAsText = True
'        .InconsistentFormula = True
'        .UnlockedFormulaCells = True
'        .EmptyCellReferences = True
'    End With
    
If This.Worksheets("TempLog").Cells(9, 151) = True Then
ChangeResolution aaa1, aaa2
End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Sub MakeTailEMF()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set This = ThisWorkbook
Dim aaa1 As Single
Dim aaa2 As Single
If This.Worksheets("TempLog").Cells(9, 151) = True Then
aaa1 = apiGetSystemMetrics(0&)
aaa2 = apiGetSystemMetrics(1&)
ChangeResolution 1280, 960
End If
Set This = ThisWorkbook
'    With Application.ErrorCheckingOptions
'        .TextDate = False
'        .NumberAsText = False
'        .InconsistentFormula = False
'        .UnlockedFormulaCells = False
'        .EmptyCellReferences = False
'    End With
    
'    If ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines Then
'        bGridOn = True
'        ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
'    End If
    
    Dim vFile As Variant, sFilter As String, lPicType As Long, oPic As IPictureDisp
    sFilter = "Windows Metafile (*.emf),*.emf"
    vFile = This.Worksheets("TempLog").Cells(1, 152) & "RT_tail.emf"
    
        'Get the type of bitmap
        lPicType = xlPicture
    
        'Copy a picture to the clipboard
         This.Worksheets("Logs RT").Range(Cells(70, 2), Cells(78, 32)).Select
        With Selection
            .CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
        End With

    
        'Retrieve the picture from the clipboard...
        Set oPic = PastePicture(lPicType)
    
        '... and save it to the file
        SavePicture oPic, vFile

'    If bGridOn Then ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = True
'
'    With Application.ErrorCheckingOptions
'        .TextDate = True
'        .NumberAsText = True
'        .InconsistentFormula = True
'        .UnlockedFormulaCells = True
'        .EmptyCellReferences = True
'    End With
If This.Worksheets("TempLog").Cells(9, 151) = True Then
ChangeResolution aaa1, aaa2
End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub UpdateRtLogsandEMF_woDepth()
Set This = ThisWorkbook
Dim aaa1 As Single
Dim aaa2 As Single
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
This.Worksheets("TempSQL").Visible = xlSheetVisible
This.Worksheets("TempLog").Visible = xlSheetVisible
This.Worksheets("TempLog").Select

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
sCon = This.Worksheets("TempSQL").Cells(1, 1)
cn.Open sCon

'DrillDepthIndex = This.Worksheets("TempLog").Cells(1, 157)
'DrillDepthIndex = "'" & DrillDepthIndex & "'"

'WellPathIndex = This.Worksheets("TempLog").Cells(1, 154)
'WellPathIndex = "'" & WellPathIndex & "'"

'Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
'sql_query = "SELECT Depth FROM GENDATAINDEX WHERE GenDataSetId = " & DrillDepthIndex & "ORDER BY Time DESC"
'rs.Open sql_query, cn
'On Error Resume Next
'sss = rs.Fields(0)
'If sss = "" Then
'This.Worksheets("Logs RT").Cells(14, 19) = ""
'Else
'This.Worksheets("Logs RT").Cells(14, 19) = Round(rs.Fields(0), 2)
'End If
'This.Worksheets("Logs RT").Cells(14, 19) = Round(rs.Fields(0), 2)

Date1 = Format(Now, "yyyy.mm.dd")
Day1 = Right(Date1, 2)
Year1 = Left(Date1, 4)
Month1 = Mid(Date1, 6, 2)

This.Worksheets("Logs RT").Cells(11, 15) = Day1 & " " & This.Worksheets("Logs RT").Cells(Month1, 43) & " " & Year1

This.Worksheets("Logs RT").Cells(12, 15) = Format(Now, "HH:mm")
This.Worksheets("Logs RT").Select

'Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
'sql_query = "SELECT SRSP_S_VDEPTH FROM SURVEY_STATION WHERE PATH_IDENTIFIER = " & WellPathIndex & " ORDER BY SRSP_TIME DESC"
'rs.Open sql_query, cn
'On Error Resume Next
'sss = rs.Fields(0)
'If sss = "" Then
'This.Worksheets("Logs RT").Cells(14, 62) = ""
'Else
'This.Worksheets("Logs RT").Cells(14, 62) = Round(rs.Fields(0), 2)
'End If
If This.Worksheets("TempLog").Cells(9, 151) = True Then
aaa1 = apiGetSystemMetrics(0&)
aaa2 = apiGetSystemMetrics(1&)
ChangeResolution 1280, 960
End If

'  With Application.ErrorCheckingOptions
'        .TextDate = False
'        .NumberAsText = False
'        .InconsistentFormula = False
'        .UnlockedFormulaCells = False
'        .EmptyCellReferences = False
'    End With
    
'    If ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines Then
'        bGridOn = True
'        ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
'    End If
    
    Dim vFile As Variant, sFilter As String, lPicType As Long, oPic As IPictureDisp
    sFilter = "Windows Metafile (*.emf),*.emf"
    vFile = This.Worksheets("TempLog").Cells(1, 152) & "RT_header_MD.emf"

        lPicType = xlPicture
 
         This.Worksheets("Logs RT").Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(67, 32)).Select
        With Selection
            .CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
        End With
        Set oPic = PastePicture(lPicType)
        SavePicture oPic, vFile


    sFilter = "Windows Metafile (*.emf),*.emf"
    vFile = This.Worksheets("TempLog").Cells(1, 152) & "RT_header_TVD.emf"

        lPicType = xlPicture
         This.Worksheets("Logs RT").Range(Cells(2, 45), Cells(67, 75)).Select
        With Selection
            .CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
        End With
        Set oPic = PastePicture(lPicType)
        SavePicture oPic, vFile

 '   If bGridOn Then ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = True
     
'    With Application.ErrorCheckingOptions
'        .TextDate = True
'        .NumberAsText = True
'        .InconsistentFormula = True
'        .UnlockedFormulaCells = True
'        .EmptyCellReferences = True
'    End With
    
If This.Worksheets("TempLog").Cells(9, 151) = True Then
ChangeResolution aaa1, aaa2
End If
    
    
This.Worksheets("Logs RT").Select
This.Worksheets("TempSQL").Visible = xlSheetHidden
This.Worksheets("TempLog").Visible = xlSheetHidden
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Debugger stops at "SavePicture oPic, vFile"

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` is hiding any errors - comment that out and see what happens.

Comment: Hi, sorry for being dumb, but what do you mean with "comment that out"?

Comment: https://excelchamps.com/vba/comment/

Comment: That's a lot of code to sift through on SO,

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line that errors, and then when it errors, check the values of your variables to see if they are what you think they should be.